# Unable to send v3 trap using snmptrap

Tags: snmpd, net-snmp, snmp

I am trying to send snmp v3 trap using snmptrap command on ubuntu 12. I tried:

```
sudo snmptrap -v 3 -c 1 localhost -a MD5 -A abcdefgh -l noAuthNoPriv -u myuser

sudo snmptrap -v 3 -c 1 localhost -a MD5 -A 1.2.3 -l noAuthNoPriv -u myuser

sudo snmptrap -v 3 localhost -a MD5 -A 1.2.3 -l noAuthNoPriv -u myuser
```

but keep getting:

```
-A: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> -A)
```

I also tried:

```
sudo snmptrap -v 3  -a MD5 -A abcdefgh -l noAuthNoPriv -u myuser localhost:162
```

and got:

```
Missing up-time parameter
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong.